# Disable index shifting to create friction shifting possible?

Tags: shifting

I have a 6 speed freewheel on a Diamondback. I tried to replace some busted shifters with an 8 speed indexing shifter that was on clearance. It appears that each shift's spacing of the shifters is going to be a little smaller than that of the gears.( It takes about 7 shifts to cover the 6 gears ) Can I turn off the indexing in the shifters so that they work as a friction shifter? If not, I will have to check out recycled cycles for and old 6 speed set. Should have done that first. Don't know if 6 speed shifters are even made/sold new anymore. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, this is a problem these days, with so many different "standards" for gears.  One suspects that the bike companies are doing it on purpose, to more quickly obsolete older bikes.

Answer (score 1):

Typically not -- a few index shifters (like my Shimano 105SC 7 speed ones) have this option, but its primarily downtube and bar end ones for <=8 speeds. I don't think there exist any other shifters that do this other than possibly some grip shifts since they pretty much are letting pawls catch.

However, you can buy friction shifters [pretty cheaply these days](http://www.jensonusa.com/!2FE-gZIjoj-efpVOUVK21A!/Sunrace-MTB-Friction-Shift-Lever?utm_source=FRGL&utm_medium=organic) from companies like Sunrace.

Comment: Older mountain bike thumb shifters also have a friction option.

Comment: Yeah, but by 8 speed, they were long gone. On the other hand, you could get downtube/barcons whcih could switch from friction and indexed til 9 or 10 speed.

Comment: OP need 6 speed, not 8.

Comment: Yes, OP realized that on their own. But, if you have a friction shifter, it doesn't care about speeds.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about a twist shifter, they DO make those still! Sram makes a [shimano compatible version](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001A0AIIS). Know that the MRX is shimano, and the other models that have numbers are sram only.
If thats not to your liking, the thumb-shifter that Batman was mentioning is a solid option for a few bucks!